# What to do in this situation AJAX/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Basically i have a huuuuuge ajax/javascript/php script
(i know it is prob far from good/optimized but it is what it is)

I am making a rating script, but when a user has already votet all the images in the database a button will be added to the dom which makes it possible to "shuffle" through the rated images... but right now the shuffle button works by calling the AJAX function with fixed values newImage(5, 5, checked);

(see shuffleRefresh() in main.js)

But these values are like voting the image with id "5" and giving it a "5" as rating.... how do i do this in a smarter way? it seems stupid to me to do it like this... what can i do here?

Index.php

```
$dbCon = dbCon();

if (isset($_POST['submitTrun'])) {
    $sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE rating_users";
    $dbCon->query($sql);
    $_POST['submitTrun'] = array();
}

$sql = "SELECT id, views, rating, votes FROM rating ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = $dbCon->query($sql);
$result = $result->fetch_object();
$id = $result->id;
$votes = $result->votes;
$views = $result->views;
$rating = $result->rating;

$average = averageRate($rating, $votes);

//UPDATERE DATABASED
$stmt = $dbCon->prepare("UPDATE rating SET
    views = views + 1 WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();

;

$ip = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

$sql = " SELECT user_ip, user_source, user_vote FROM rating_users WHERE user_ip = $ip AND user_source = $id";
$result = $dbCon->query($sql);
$result = $result->fetch_object();
$rating = $result->user_vote;
if (empty($result)) {
    //BILLEDE + DENS VALUE
    $imgRating .= "<img id=\"imgSrc\" src=\"assets/img/$id.jpg\" class=\"babeImg boxsb show\">";
    $imgRating .= "<input id=\"imgValue\" class=\"absolute displayn\" type=\"radio\" value=\"$id\">";

    $starRating = "";
    for ($i = 5; $i > 0; $i--) {
        $starRating .= "<input id=\"vote$i\" class=\"vote displayn\" type=\"radio\" name=\"vote\" value=\"$i\">";
        $starRating .= "<label id=\"voteLabel$i\" class=\"voteHover\" for=\"vote$i\"></label>";
    }

    $starRating .= "<input type=\"submit\" id=\"voteSubmit\" class=\"displayn\">";
    //STAR FORM END
    $voteYesNo = "voteYes";
    $voteText = "Du kan vote";
} else {

    $sql = "SELECT user_vote FROM rating_users WHERE user_ip = $ip AND user_source = $id";
    $result1 = $dbCon->query($sql);
    $result1 = $result1->fetch_object();
    $user_vote = $result1->user_vote;

    $imgRating = "<img id=\"imgSrc\" src=\"assets/img/$id.jpg\" class=\"babeImg boxsb show\">";
    $imgRating .= "<input id=\"imgValue\" class=\"absolute displayn\" type=\"radio\" value=\"$id\">";

    $starRating;
    for ($i = $user_vote; $i < 5; $i++) {
        $starRating .= "<div class=\"voteEmpty\"></div>";
    }
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $user_vote; $i++) {
        $starRating .= "<div class=\"voteFull\"></div>";
    }

    $shuffleImg = "<img id=\"shuffleImg\" class=\"shuffleImg\" src=\"assets/img/refresh.png\" alt=\"refresh\">";

    $voteYesNo = "voteNo";
    $voteText = "Du har votet";//VOTABLE
}
?>
<a href="index.php?page=contribuate" class="absolute top0 right0 zdeks1">Contribuate</a>
<div class="flex row100">
    <div class="absolute left0 top0">
        <form action="" method="post" class="absolute left0 top0 zdeks1">
            <input id="submitTrun" type="submit" name="submitTrun">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col100 row100 bgc2 relative vh100 selectn flex-dc flex">
        <div class="categoryWrapper relative flex center col100 padt20">
            <input id="catBooty" class="kategorier " type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1">
            <label for="catBooty" class="pointer"><img src="assets/img/booty.png" alt="The Booty Way"></label>

            <input id="catBooby" class="kategorier " type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="2">
            <label for="catBooby" class="pointer"><img src="assets/img/booby.png" alt="The Booby Way"></label>

            <input id="catPantsy" class="kategorier" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="3">
            <label for="catPantsy" class="pointer"><img src="assets/img/pantsy.png" alt="The Pantsy Way"></label>
        </div>


        <div id="globalRating2" class="globalRating2 col100 relative flex center flex1 overflowh">

            <div id="globalRating" class="inlineb relative leftIn">
                <div id="innerGlobalRating" class="innerGlobalRating flex bgc1">
                    <div id="imgInfoWrap" class="imgInfoWrap relative top0 left0 pad10 flex flex-dc">
                        <p id="imgViews" class="views alignic flex cursdef cw"><?php echo $views; ?></p>
                        <p id="imgVotes" class="votes alignic flex cursdef cw"><?php echo $votes; ?> </p>
                        <p id="imgAverage" class="average alignic flex cursdef cw"><?php echo $average; ?>/5</p>
                        <p id="votedYesNo" class="<?php echo $voteYesNo ?> alignic flex cursdef cw"><?php echo $voteText ?></p>
                        <div class="alignfe flex1 flex">
                            <p id="imgTime" class="imgTime alignic flex cursdef cw padt5">27/03/2017</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="imgInnerWrap" class="relative flex bgc1">
                        <div id="imgInner" class="imgInner relative">
                            <div id="shuffleImgWrap" class="shuffleImgWrap absolute top0 right0 mar15">
                                <?php
                            if (isset($shuffleImg)) {
                                echo $shuffleImg;
                            }
                                ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                            if (isset($imgRating)) {
                                echo $imgRating;
                            }
                            ?>
                        </div>


                        <div id="starWrapper" class="starWrapper flex center flex-drr absolute col100 bot0">
                            <?php echo $starRating; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

main.js

```
function hasChild(parent, ids) {
    return parent.querySelector(ids) !== null;
//    var hasChild = parentDiv.querySelector("#child2") != null;
}

function hasClass(element, cls) {
    return element.classList.contains(cls);
}

function createElement(type, attributes, someElement) {
    var element = document.createElement(type);
    for (var key in attributes) {
        if (key === "class") {
            var cls = attributes[key];
            for (var c in cls)
                element.classList.add(cls[c]);
        } else {
            element[key] = attributes[key];
        }
    }
    someElement.appendChild(element);
}

var kategorier = document.getElementsByClassName("kategorier");
var kategorierLength = kategorier.length;
let checked = "1,2,3";
for (let i = 0; i < kategorierLength; i++) {
    kategorier[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        checked = '';
        for (var k = 0; k < kategorierLength; k++) {
            if (checked) {

                var separator = ',';
            } else {
                var separator = '';
            }
            if (kategorier[k].checked) {
                checked += separator + kategorier[k].value;
            }
        }
        console.log(checked);
    });
}

function starRating() {
    var vote = document.getElementsByClassName('vote');
    var voteL = vote.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < voteL; i++) {
        let voteValue = vote[i].value;
        vote[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            var imgValue = document.getElementById("imgValue").value;
            newImage(voteValue, imgValue, checked);
            console.log(vote[i].value);
        });
    }
}
setTimeout(starRating, 500);

function shuffleRefresh() {
    if (document.getElementById("shuffleImgWrap")) {
        var shuffleImgWrap = document.getElementById("shuffleImgWrap");
        shuffleImgWrap.addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (document.getElementById("shuffleImg") !== null) {
                var shuffleImg = document.getElementById("shuffleImg");
                newImage(5, 5, checked);
            }
        });
    }
}
shuffleRefresh();

function newImage(voteValue, imgValue, checked) {
    if (checked === "") {
    } else {
        var imgSrc = document.getElementById('imgSrc');
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "pages/newImage.php";
        var params = "voteValue=" + voteValue + "&imgValue=" + imgValue + "&checked=" + checked;
        http.open("POST", url, true);
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        http.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (http.readyState === 4 && http.status === 200) {
                var globalRating2 = document.getElementById("globalRating2");
                var globalRating = document.getElementById("globalRating");
                var innerGlobalRating = document.getElementById("innerGlobalRating");
                var imgValue = document.getElementById('imgValue');

                console.log(this.responseText);

                var jsonData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                var content = jsonData.content;
                if (jsonData.views) {
                    $views = jsonData.views;
                }
                if (jsonData.votes) {
                    $votes = jsonData.votes;
                }
                if (jsonData.average) {
                    $average = jsonData.average += "/5";
                }
                if (jsonData.imgSrc) {
                    var imgSrc = jsonData.imgSrc;
                }
                if (jsonData.id) {
                    var jsonId = jsonData.id;
                }
                //LEFT SLIDE START
                if (hasClass(globalRating, "leftIn")) {
                    globalRating.classList.remove("leftIn");
                    globalRating.classList.add("leftOut");
                }

                setTimeout(newContent, 500);
                function newContent() {
                    while (globalRating2.firstChild) {
                        globalRating2.removeChild(globalRating2.firstChild);
                    }

                    if (content === "newImg" || content === "ratedImg") {
                        var newElement = createElement("div", {
                            "id": "globalRating",
                            "class": ["inlineb", "relative", "leftIn"]
                        }, globalRating2);
                        var globalRating = document.getElementById("globalRating");


                        var newDiv = createElement("div", {
                            "id": "innerGlobalRating",
                            "class": ["innerGlobalRating", "flex", "bgc1", "boxsb"]
                        }, globalRating);
                        var innerGlobalRating = document.getElementById("innerGlobalRating");

                        var imgInfoWrap = document.getElementById("imgInfoWrap");
                        var newDiv = createElement("div", {
                            "id": "imgInfoWrap",
                            "class": ["imgInfoWrap", "relative", "top0", "left0", "pad10", "flex", "flex-dc"]
                        }, innerGlobalRating);
                        var imgInfoWrap = document.getElementById("imgInfoWrap");
                        var newParagraph = createElement("p", {
                            "id": "imgViews",
                            "class": ["views", "alignic", "flex", "cursdef", "cw"]
                        }, imgInfoWrap);
                        var newParagraph = createElement("p", {
                            "id": "imgVotes",
                            "class": ["votes", "alignic", "flex", "cursdef", "cw"]
                        }, imgInfoWrap);
                        var newParagraph = createElement("p", {
                            "id": "imgAverage",
                            "class": ["average", "alignic", "flex", "cursdef", "cw"]
                        }, imgInfoWrap);

                        var imgViews = document.getElementById("imgViews");
                        var imgVotes = document.getElementById("imgVotes");
                        var imgAverage = document.getElementById("imgAverage");

                        imgViews.innerText = $views;
                        imgVotes.innerText = $votes;
                        imgAverage.innerText = $average;

                        var newDiv = createElement("div", {
                            "id": "imgInnerWrap",
                            "class": ["relative", "flex"]
                        }, innerGlobalRating);
                        var imgInnerWrap = document.getElementById("imgInnerWrap");

                        var newDiv = createElement("div", {
                            "id": "imgInner",
                            "class": ["imgInner", "relative"]
                        }, imgInnerWrap);
                        var imgInner = document.getElementById("imgInner");

                        var newImg = createElement("img", {
                            "id": "imgSrc",
                            "class": ["babeImg", "boxsb", "show"],
                            "src": imgSrc
                        }, imgInner);
                        var starWrapper = document.getElementById("starWrapper");
                        var imgInner = document.getElementById("imgInner");

                        var newDiv = createElement("div", {
                            "id": "starWrapper",
                            "class": ["starWrapper", "flex", "center", "flex-drr", "absolute", "col100", "bot0"]
                        }, imgInner);
                        var starWrapper = document.getElementById("starWrapper");
                        var imgInner = document.getElementById("imgInner");

                        var newDiv = createElement("input", {
                            "id": "imgValue",
                            "class": ["absolute", "displayn"],
                            "type": "radio",
                            "value": jsonId
                        }, imgInner);

                        if (content === "newImg") {
                            for (i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
                                var newDiv = createElement("input", {
                                    "id": "vote" + i,
                                    "class": ["vote", "displayn"],
                                    "type": "radio",
                                    "name": "vote",
                                    "value": i
                                }, starWrapper);

                                var newDiv = createElement("label", {
                                    "id": "voteLabel" + i,
                                    "class": ["voteHover"],
                                    "htmlFor": "vote" + i
                                }, starWrapper);
                            }
                            starRating();
                        } else if (content === "ratedImg") {
                            var newDiv = createElement("div", {
                                "id": "shuffleImgWrap",
                                "class": ["shuffleImgWrap", "absolute", "top0", "right0", "mar15"]
                            }, imgInner);
                            var shuffleImgWrap = document.getElementById("shuffleImgWrap");
                            var newDiv = createElement("img", {
                                "id": "shuffleImg",
                                "class": ["shuffleImg"],
                                "src": "assets/img/refresh.png",
                                "alt": "refresh"
                            }, shuffleImgWrap);
                            shuffleRefresh();

                            alert("newImg");

                        }
                        setTimeout(slideIn, 500);
                        function slideIn() {
                            var globalRating = document.getElementById("globalRating");
                            if (hasClass(globalRating, "leftOut")) {
                                globalRating.classList.remove("leftOut");
                            }
                            globalRating.classList.add("leftIn");
                        }
                    }
                    if (content === "versus") {

                        var newDiv = createElement("div", {
                            "id": "innerGlobalRating",
                            "class": ["innerGlobalRating", "flex", "bgc1", "boxsb", "leftIn", "relative"]
                        }, globalRating2);
                        var innerGlobalRating = document.getElementById("innerGlobalRating");

                        var newDiv = createElement("img", {
                            "id": "vs1",
                            "class": ["vs1", "babeVersus", "borb2"],
                            "src": "assets/img/1.jpg"
                        }, innerGlobalRating);
                        var vs1 = document.getElementById("vs1");

                        var newDiv = createElement("input", {
                            "id": "versus1",
                            "class": ["absolute", "top0", "left0"],
                            "type": "radio",
                            "name": "versus"
                        }, innerGlobalRating);

                        var newDiv = createElement("label", {
                            "class": ["trophy", "absolute", "top0", "left0", "mar10"],
                            "htmlFor": "versus1"
                        }, innerGlobalRating);


                        var newDiv = createElement("img", {
                            "id": "versusIcon",
                            "class": ["versusIcon", "flex", "center", "mar10", "bgc2"],
                            "src": "assets/img/icons/versusIcon.png"
                        }, globalRating2);
                        var versusIcon = document.getElementById("versusIcon");


                        var newDiv = createElement("div", {
                            "id": "innerGlobalRating2",
                            "class": ["innerGlobalRating2", "flex", "bgc1", "boxsb", "rightIn", "relative"]
                        }, globalRating2);
                        var innerGlobalRating2 = document.getElementById("innerGlobalRating2");

                        var newDiv = createElement("img", {
                            "id": "vs2",
                            "class": ["vs2", "babeVersus", "borb2"],
                            "src": "assets/img/2.jpg"
                        }, innerGlobalRating2);
                        var vs2 = document.getElementById("vs2");

                        var newDiv = createElement("input", {
                            "id": "versus2",
                            "class": ["absolute", "top0", "right0"],
                            "type": "radio",
                            "name": "versus"
                        }, innerGlobalRating2);

                        var newDiv = createElement("label", {
                            "class": ["trophy", "absolute", "top0", "right0", "mar10"],
                            "htmlFor": "versus2"
                        }, innerGlobalRating2);

                    } else if (content === "donation") {
                        var newDiv = createElement("div", {
                            "id": "innerGlobalRating",
                            "class": ["innerGlobalRating", "flex", "bgc1", "boxsb"]
                        }, globalRating);
                        var innerGlobalRating = document.getElementById("innerGlobalRating");
                        var newDiv = createElement("div", {
                            "id": "donationWrapper",
                            "class": ["donationWrapper", "pad20"]
                        }, innerGlobalRating);
                        var donationWrapper = document.getElementById("donationWrapper");
                        var newDiv = createElement("p", {
                            "id": "donationText",
                            "class": ["donationText", "pad10"]
                        }, donationWrapper);
                        var donationText = document.getElementById("donationText");
                        donationText.innerText = "Contribuate to keep our website running 2";

                        var newDiv = createElement("button", {
                            "id": "buttonNo",
                            "class": ["buttonNo", "pad20"]
                        }, donationWrapper);
                        var buttonNo = document.getElementById("buttonNo");
                        buttonNo.innerText = "No";
                        var newDiv = createElement("a", {
                            "id": "buttonYes",
                            "class": ["buttonYes", "pad20"],
                            "href": "index.php?page=contribuate",
                            "target": "_blank"
                        }, donationWrapper);
                        var buttonYes = document.getElementById("buttonYes");
                        buttonYes.innerText = "Yes";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ;
        http.send(params);
    }
}
```

newImage.php

```
require_once '../includes/db.php';
require_once '../includes/functions.php';
$dbCon = dbCon();

if(isset($_POST['voteValue'])){
    $voteValue = $_POST['voteValue'];
} else{
    $voteValue = 0;
}
if(isset($_POST['imgValue'])){
    $imgValue = $_POST['imgValue'];
} else{
    $imgValue = 0;
}
$checked = $_POST['checked'];

$ip = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

$sql = "SELECT user_ip, user_source FROM rating_users WHERE user_ip = $ip AND user_source = $imgValue";
$result = $dbCon->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows === 0) {

    $stmtt = $dbCon->prepare("INSERT INTO rating_users (user_ip, user_vote, user_source) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $stmtt->bind_param('iii', $ip, $voteValue, $imgValue);
    $stmtt->execute();

    $stmt = $dbCon->prepare("UPDATE rating SET
    votes = votes + 1,
    rating = rating + ? WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $voteValue, $imgValue);
    $stmt->execute();
}

$sql = " SELECT user_ip FROM rating_users WHERE user_ip = $ip";
$result = $dbCon->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $har_stemt = 'true';

    $sql = "SELECT id FROM rating WHERE category IN ($checked)";
    $result_user_stemmer = $dbCon->query($sql);
    $arr_alle_billeder;
    $arr_alle_billeder_length = count($arr_alle_billeder);
    while ($obj = $result_user_stemmer->fetch_object()) {
        $arr_alle_billeder[] = $obj->id;
    }

    $arr_alle_billeder_int = [];
    $arr_alle_billeder_length = count($arr_alle_billeder);

    foreach ($arr_alle_billeder as $key => $val) {
        $arr_alle_billeder_int[$key] = intval($val);
    }
    $sql = "SELECT user_source FROM rating_users WHERE user_ip = $ip";
    $result_user_stemmer = $dbCon->query($sql);
    // LAVER #2 ARRAY MED ALLE DE STEMTE BILLEDER
    $arr_user_har_stemt_paa;
    while ($obj = $result_user_stemmer->fetch_object()) {
        // for hver user_source billedet IKKE skal vises
        $arr_user_har_stemt_paa[] = $obj->user_source;
    }

    $arr_resterende_billeder = array_diff($arr_alle_billeder_int, $arr_user_har_stemt_paa);

    $random_key = array_rand($arr_resterende_billeder);

    $id = $arr_resterende_billeder[$random_key];

    function myDice() {
        $dice = rand(1, 100);
        if ($dice > 0 && $dice <= 50) {
            return 1;
        } else if ($dice > 50 && $dice <= 99) { //75%
            return 2;
        } else if ($dice > 99 && $dice <= 100) { //10%
            return 3;
        }
    }
    $dice = myDice();

    if ($dice === 1) {

        if ($id) {

            $sql = "SELECT views, votes, rating FROM rating WHERE id = $id";
            $result = $dbCon->query($sql);
            $result = $result->fetch_object();
            $views = $result->views;
            $votes = $result->votes;
            $rating = $result->rating;
            $average = averageRate($rating, $votes);

            $imgSrc = "assets/img/" . $id . ".jpg";
            $arr = ['content' => 'newImg', 'imgSrc' => $imgSrc, 'id' => $id, 'checked' => $checked, 'views' => $views, 'votes' => $votes, 'average' => $average, 'dice' => $dice];
            $stmt = $dbCon->prepare("UPDATE rating SET
            views = views + 1 WHERE id = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
            $stmt->execute();

            echo json_encode($arr);
        } else { //$sql = "SELECT id, views, votes, rating FROM rating WHERE id <> $imgValue AND category IN ($checked) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
            //$sql = "SELECT id, views, votes, rating FROM rating WHERE category IN ($checked) AND id <> $imgValue ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
            $sql = "SELECT id, views, votes, rating FROM rating WHERE category IN ($checked) AND id <> $imgValue ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
            $result = $dbCon->query($sql);
            $result = $result->fetch_object();
            $id = $result->id;
            $views = $result->views;
            $votes = $result->votes;
            $rating = $result->rating;

            $sql = "SELECT user_vote FROM rating_users WHERE user_ip = $ip AND user_source = $id";
            $result1 = $dbCon->query($sql);
            $result1 = $result1->fetch_object();
            $user_vote = $result1->user_vote;

            $imgSrc = "assets/img/" . $id . ".jpg";
            $average = averageRate($rating, $votes);
            $arr = ['content' => 'ratedImg', 'imgSrc' => $imgSrc, 'id' => $id, 'checked' => $checked, 'views' => $views, 'votes' => $votes, 'average' => $average, 'user_vote' => $user_vote, 'dice' => $dice];
            echo json_encode($arr);
        }
    }
    if ($dice === 2) {
        $arr = ['content' => 'versus', 'dice' => $dice, 'vs1' => 'someImg1', 'vs2' => 'someImg2'];
        echo json_encode($arr);
    }

    if ($dice === 3) {
        $arr = ['content' => 'donation', 'dice' => $dice];
        echo json_encode($arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: For some of your queries - [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: I already use prepared statements... i know some are not with params/really prepared yet, but i will re design them all before launch :)

Comment: This is way too much code. I don't want to dig through this to try and debug something. Try making a [minimum example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it's more readable.